# Error with shared library as "invalid conversion" from void * to double(*) (int*)?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Hi i am trying to implement shared library (dynamic linking) below is the code i am getting error as below please help me to fix it

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘double (*)(int*)’ [-fpermissive]
  fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");
```

**ctest1.c**

```c
void ctest1(int *i)
{
   *i=5;
 }
```

Above ctest1.c is the shared library which is used in the below hello.cc file

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "ctest1.h"  // here i have declared the function of shared library

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   void *lib_handle;
   void (*fn)(int *);
   int x=990;
   char *error;

   lib_handle = dlopen("libp.so", RTLD_LAZY);  // opening the shared library
   if (!lib_handle)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
      exit(1);
   }

 fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");  //storing the address of shared library function 
   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
      exit(1);
   }

   fn(&x);
   printf("getting x value from shared library=%d\n",x);

   dlclose(lib_handle);
   return 0;
}
```

~
~
~

Answer (score 3):

You are simply invoking the wrong compiler. In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you can't convert from `void *` to another pointer type without casting. If this is not your code then, the lack of a cast means that the code is [c](/questions/tagged/c) instead of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Please read the tags wiki to understand, c and c++ are not the same language, they are somewhat similar but, certainly not the same.

This is from draft n1570 of the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 1. A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

If it's your code you should distinguish between c and c++ by using the appropriate file extension, or force the compiler to use the appropriate compiler which I don't recommend, just fix the file extension.

Comment: can you please elaborate it and help me to fix the problem thanks

Comment: first i created object file as gcc -c ctest1.c then after creating a object file then created a shared library using command gcc -shared -o libp.so ctest1.o after creating shared library then i compiled main code as  gcc -g -rdynamic -o progdl dynamic.cc -ldl

Comment: `a pointer to any object type` and a `function pointer` are not compatible.

Comment: @mhc Can you please support that assertion?

Answer (score 1):

`dlsym` returns a `void*` and you are trying to store that in the function pointer. You have to use a cast for it to succeed when using c++ (assuming from tags and file ending .cc, though your code is actually C).

Also your type claims the function has a return type of `double` but your library function returns `void`. This will have to be fixed or you will get runtime problems.

Comment: That doesn't change what you just clarified, does it?